# Issue updating the 'video_metadata' column of a video model in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm currently facing an issue while trying to update the `'video_metadata'` column of a video model in Laravel. I have attempted two different approaches, but only the first method seems to work.

Here are the two ways I have tried:

1.Working approach:

```
Video::where('id', $this->video->getKey())->update([
   'video_metadata->author_id' => 2
]);
```

2.Not working approach:

```
$this->video->update([
   'video_metadata->author_id' => 2
]);
```

I'm confused as to why the second approach is not working. Both methods seem similar to me, but only the first one successfully updates the `'video_metadata'` column. Could someone please explain why the second approach is not working and suggest a solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The first method **uses a Query Builder to update the database**. This doesn't call Eloquent model instances like `events` or `mutators`. It directly modifies the database based on the condition specified. (`WHERE id = 'xyz'`)

But the second method **uses the Eloquent model instance to update the database**, which means it trigger `events` and uses `mutators`.

However the issue is ***second method doesn't work with updating JSON columns directly***

---

The solution you can try are

```
$metadata = $this->video->video_metadata;
$metadata['author_id'] = 2;
$this->video->video_metadata = $metadata;
$this->video->save();
```

or

```
$this->video->video_metadata = array_merge((array) $this->video->video_metadata, ['author_id' => 2]);
$this->video->save();
```